# Evaluate string closure as a "real" closure

Tags: php, string, closures

I am trying to pass a closure argument to a function. The closure is in my database and is stored as a string.

When I pass my closure to the function I got the error:

> Argument 1 passed to ...::__construct() must be an instance of Closure, string given...

I have the bellow closure that is just a string

```
function () use ($titleItem) {
            $titleValue = $titleItem->getExtractedValue();
            $this->setAttributes('a', ['target' => '_blank', 'rel' => 'nofollow']);
            \ToolBox::replaceImagesAttributes($this, $titleValue, 'storage/path');
};
```

Is there any way to convert this string as a real closure?

Comment: Will [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) do what you want, albeit dangerously?

Comment: unfortunately no, just return null

Comment: Edit your question and add your code

Comment: Are the beginning and ending quotes `"` actual part of the string in the DB?

Comment: no, it just a demonstration

Comment: Is it that you can't get `eval()` to work or that you can't use it?

Comment: Calling `eval()` on a string that simply defines a closure doesn't return a handle to the closure, so you can never call it. If you adjust the string and add something like `$closure = ` at the start, then you'll have a handle that you can pass. But that is a terrible idea, don't do that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I think the whole idea of having code stored in the database is going to be a huge risk anyway you do it.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, hence the bit about it being a terrible idea. :)

Comment: This design is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I would never store source code in the database. It requires dangerous `eval()` gyrations, is very difficult to test properly, and precludes the use of source control, static analysis, coding style, and deployment tools. It's hard to recommend an alternative without understanding your app, but you might instead store a string containing the name of  a class/method to call. E.g., no code, just a function name that must already exist. Then you can invoke via `call_user_func()` and no `eval()` is required.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you very much for your help. I will refactoring my code